# User Friendly Unique Identifier For DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

In my DynamoDB table named `users`, I need a unique identifier, which is easy for users to remember.

In a RDBMS I can use auto increment id to meet the requirement.

As there is no way to have auto increment id in DynamoDB, is there a way to meet this requirement?

If I keep last used id in another table (`lastIdTable`) retrieve it before adding new document, increment that number and save updated numbers in both tables (`lastIdTable` and `users`), that will be very inefficient.

**UPDATE**

Please note that there's no way of using an existing attribute or getting users input for this purpose.

Comment: Could you let users pick their own username?

Comment: @MatthewPope unfortunately no way of getting user's inputs in this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Since it seems you must create a memorable userId without any information about the user, I’d recommend that you create a random phrase of 2-4 simple words from a standard dictionary.

For example, you might generate the phrase [correct horse battery staple](https://xkcd.com/936/). (I know this is a userId and not a password, but the memorability consideration still applies.)

[image: https://imgs.xkcd.com/936/]

Whether you use a random number (which has similar memorability to a sequential number) or a random phrase (which I think is much more memorable), you will need to do a conditional write with the condition that the ID does not already exist, and if it does exist, you should generate a new ID and try again.

Answer (score 0):

email address seems the best choice...

Either as a partition key, or use a GUID as the partition key and have a Global Secondary Index over email address.

Or as Matthew suggested in a comment, let the users pick a user name.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no way of using existing attribute or getting user's inputs. I will update the question.

Answer (score 0):

Docker container naming strategy might give you some idea. https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/pkg/namesgenerator/names-generator.go
It will result in unique (limited) yet human friendly

**Examples**

```
awesome_einstein
nasty_weinstein
perv_epstein
```

A similar one: https://github.com/jjmontesl/codenamize

Comment: `perv_epstein` holy moly